# How to implement "Go to top" functionality?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I am working with ExtJS4 and looking for a way to implement "Go to top" functionality.

i.e. On the click of "top" button, the view should scroll back to the top of the component. How can I achieve this in ExtJS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to rixo's answer (*which would be the easiest way for scrolling to the absolute top*) I want to mention that there is also a implementation on component level (**[scrollBy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-scrollBy)**) which can be handy if you don't have to scroll the whole window.

**Update**

I must confess I never used `scrollBy` myself so if it don't work out for you (the linked API should provide you with all infomration) I recommend you to use **[scrollTo()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-scrollTo)** instead. Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/NVk9r/)

Use it on Panel like

```
panel.getEl().scrollTo('Top', 0, true);
// or
panel.body.scrollTo('Top', 0, true); // this property is protected
// or 
panel.getTargetEl().scrollTo('Top', 0, true); // this method is private and may be changed
```

and on a Treepanel or Gridpanel like

```
panel.getView().getEl().scrollTo('Top', 0, true);
```

Comment: Thanx for reply...Actually i have all my views as panel. So "window.scrollTo(0,0)" is not working. So how to implement this in case of panel?

Comment: As per you told mam, i have written code as-         "    panel=Ext.getCmp('qbqnsId');
    panel.getEl().scrollTo('Top', 0, true);"                              and i have this panel view code as-"Ext.define('Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.Qbqns', {
 extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',

 requires : [ 'Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.QbqnsView' ],
 id : 'qbqnsId',
 alias : 'widget.Qbqns',
 title : 'Qbqns',
 autoScroll : true,

 items : [ {
  xtype : 'QbqnsView'
 }],
 buttons : [ {
  xtype : 'button',
  fieldLabel : 'Vote',
  action : 'voteAction',
  formBind : true,
  text : 'submit'}]});"  But its not working.

Comment: @user1722857 Use `body` [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/jKFhD/)  instead of `getEl()` or the private method `getTargetEl()`

Comment: Thanx for helping me..Actually i tried as per you told. i modified my view as-"Ext.define('Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.Qbqns', {
 extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',

 requires : [ 'Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.QbqnsView' ],
 id : 'qbqnsId',
 alias : 'widget.Qbqns',
 title : 'Qbqns',
    autoScroll: true,

 items : [ {
  xtype : 'QbqnsView'
   } ],
 buttons : [ {
  xtype : 'button',
  fieldLabel : 'Vote',
  action : 'voteAction',
  name : 'vote',
  formBind : true,
  text : 'submit'
  
    handler: function(btn) { btn.up('panel').body.scrollTo('Top', 0, true)
    };
 } ]
});" But still its not working.

Comment: @user1722857 I extended your tags a bit. Well might be getting the wrong panel! You are extending a form so you should try to call btn.up('form') or better btn.up('Qbqns'). btw. the convention for xtype is lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`window.scrollTo(0,0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scrollTo) in your click handler.